# Issue with android java event listener

Tags: java, android

I made a app in android studio it works fine but before app starts functioning it must retrieve data from Firebase real time database. this takes very few seconds so i decided to put another layout which will be displayed as starting screen and as soon as data loads we come back to original app so i made these changes

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference brightn = database.getReference("INIT_DATA");
    brightn.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            -display data-
            .....
        }
           .......
```

if i do like this app crashes always and if i add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` after ending of event listener then app is not cashing but startscreen disappears after a second getting activity_main screen and few seconds later data was displayed.

this was like event listener was running later the code below it runs.
help me with this issue

Comment: Please post the crash logs.

Comment: there is no compilation error but when i run it on my phone app stops immediately and system says app keep stopping report app or close app.

Comment: yeah, I was asking about the same i.e. crash logs. Copy it from logcat.

Comment: (logcat)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/11R7tFFjEy2xK33lzxlytNJWGcBsKXHo-/view?usp=sharing] and full (java code)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwm65IaOHFWKQLB4tnMnyhRdlQhkhPyS/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Multiple `NullPointerException` because the views object should have been created after `setContentView()`.

Comment: yes because event listener was running after code below it runs this is my first app so please help me how can i do it in another way

Comment: actual project is IOT based and with mobile app we can monitor and control data. I also pasted java code help me what i have to do like any alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until you set the content view to initialize and `setOnClickListener()` in your view like this :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // try to make these objects private
    private Button buttonOFF;
    private Button buttonON;
    private SeekBar brightnessSlider;
    private TextView brightnessDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loadlayout);


        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference brighten = database.getReference("LED_BRIGHTNESS");

        brighten.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                int value = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                // initialize views only now after setting the layout
                initViews();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), "Error Occurred", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // here you need to set another view which shows some error has occurred.
            }
        });

    }

    // method to initialize and set onClickListener which will only be called after setting view
    void initViews(){
        brightnessSlider = findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
        brightnessDisplay = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        brightnessSlider.setProgress(value);
        brightnessDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(value));

        buttonOFF = findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonON = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        brightnessSlider = findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
        brightnessDisplay = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        buttonOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Write a message to the database
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("LED_STATUS");//LED_STATUS is Firebase database LED_STATUS
                myRef.setValue(0);
            }
        });
        buttonON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("LED_STATUS");//LED_STATUS is Firebase database LED_STATUS
                myRef.setValue(1);
            }
        });
        brightnessSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("LED_BRIGHTNESS");//LED_STATUS is Firebase database LED_STATUS
                myRef.setValue(i);
                brightnessDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.firebase);

//        int fair = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/download", null, this.getPackageName());
//        logo.setImageResource(fair);
//        I guess we can easily set the drawable like this
        logo.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.download));
    }
}
```